# Hibernate: Entity is not mapped

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using using spring boot and `Native Query`, here is my query

```
 List<Employee> pageData = em.createQuery(" select max(case when UPPER(property_name)='FIRST_NAME' then value end) as firstName,max(case when UPPER(property_name)='LAST_NAME' then value end) as lastName from employee e join employeedetails ed on e.id = cd.empdetail_id ORDER BY "+ orderedBy , Employee.class)
            .setFirstResult(10*page).setMaxResults(size).getResultList();
```

where `orderedBy = firstName ASC`

And `Employee` class looks like

```
public interface Employee{
  @JsonProperty(value = "firstName")
  String getFirstName();

  @JsonProperty(value = "LastName")
  String getLastName();

  // and so on
  }
```

But i am getting exception  `employee is not mapped`

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: employee is not mapped [my query]
```

with root cause

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: employee is not mapped
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3695) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Comment: Share the caused by statement from logs.

Comment: You should map your class with your database. You can use annotations or hibernate.xml files.

Comment: @hurricane what annotation i can try , let me post the Employee class

Comment: Check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your query there is:

```
select ... from employee ...
```

To execute this query, there must exist an entity with name "employee". The error message means there is no such entity.

What can you do?

1. Check if there is a class named "Employee" and annotated with `@Entity`. What you show is an interface, not a class. Hibernate ignores it.
2. Check if there is a class with any name and annotated with `@Entity(name = "employee")`.